# floatingsearchview RTL Layout

Tags: java, android, github, layout

I'm trying to use [floatingsearchview](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview) in my app. My app has RTL layout and when I use floatingsearchview it doesn't match with RTL layout. How can I fix it?

Here is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.arlib.floatingsearchview.FloatingSearchView
            android:id="@+id/floating_search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            app:floatingSearch_close_search_on_keyboard_dismiss="false"
            app:floatingSearch_dimBackground="false"
            app:floatingSearch_dismissOnOutsideTouch="true"
            app:floatingSearch_leftActionMode="showHamburger"
            app:floatingSearch_menu="@menu/menu_search_view"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginLeft="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginRight="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchBarMarginTop="@dimen/search_view_inset"
            app:floatingSearch_searchHint="@string/search_hint"
            app:floatingSearch_showSearchKey="true"
            app:floatingSearch_suggestionsListAnimDuration="250" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: can you show us your xml ?

Comment: I edited my topic and added codes